# Do I have to code my site with NativeScript and VueJs for a separate native app or I could just directly convert it to native?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript and I just used VueJs since last year only. I already got a working website with admin page and dashboard made with VueJs and Bootstrap for my front-end.

I have read about nativescript these past few weeks and I planned to make my website native.

Should I rewrite my website with admin functions in nativescript or could I just use nativescript to enable my website as native app in android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have coded your app with Vue or Angular and if you choose NativeScript to build your **native mobile app**, then you will be able to reuse the data model, services, basically anything that is not related to UI.

We call it **native mobile app** for a reason, your UI is pure native here, more or less equivalent to building a mobile app using Java (Android) / Objective C (iOS). You will have access to all native UI components and device apis, which is why you have to recode your UI.

What you must be looking for is something like Corodova / PhoneGap **(Hybrid mobile app)** which can just take your web app and wrap it inside a WebView.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want any phonegap solutions. I want speed though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by speed, {N} is faster but if you meant the development time, yes you will have to rewrite your UI which is going to take time.